# Prove that $D _n= \{x, d(x,B) \ge 1/N\text{ and }d(x,0) \le N \} $ is a closed set in $\mathbb R^n $

Tags: general-topology

Let $d(x,y)= |x-y | $ denote the supremum metric in $\mathbb R^n $ defined by $|x |=\max \{|x _1|,\ldots,|x _n |\} $ and let $d(x,B)= \inf \{|x-b |, b \in B \} $

Assume that $d(x,B) $ and $d(x,0) $ are continuous functions (this can be proved).

Then show that $D _n= \{x, d(x,B) \ge 1/N \text{ and }d(x,0) \le N \}  $ is a closed set in $\mathbb R^n $

($B $ is a closed set if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_n$ is the intersection of two closed sets:
$$
D _n= \{x : d(x,B) \ge 1/N \} \cap \{ x: d(x,0) \le N \}
$$
These two sets are closed because they are the inverse images of closed sets under continuous functions.

More precisely,
$$
\{x : d(x,B) \ge 1/N \} = f^{-1}([1/N,+\infty]),\ \text{for $f(x)=d(x,B)$}
$$
and
$$
\{ x: d(x,0) \le N \} = g^{-1}([0,N]),\ \text{for $g(x)=d(x,0)$}
$$

Comment: Nice! They are the preimages $d^{-1 }(c,B) $ where $c $ is the set of all $x \ge 1/N $ and $d^{-1 }(d,=) $ where d is the set of all $x \le N $, right?

Comment: See my edited answer.